# Google mail - Paypal emails going directly to trash

Tags: email, gmail

Emails coming from paypal go directly to my trash,

I noticed this today because i got a mail notification through OSx.

However when i went to find the email it wasn't there. After some digging i found it in my trash.

I logged into google and checked sessions, only mine was there.

I checked filters and forwarders and saw nothing.

Where else can i go from here to investigate, besides changing password and 2fa token?

Comment: Is it just this one or all PayPal emails? Have you specified this email as "not spam"? Are you sure it's actually from PayPal?

Comment: I've verified it not being spam, Im currently investigating a service i tested once that i think might be the culprit, Unroll.me.

Comment: Gmail automatically considers some email as spam, even if it is actually legitimate. This can be from seeing large numbers of users mark it as spam (common for bulk mails from online shops), suspicious wording (anything mentioning viagra, perhaps, even if it was in the context of "common spam subjects"), or various other reasons. See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1366858?hl=en for some examples

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with a mailing list unsubscription service unroll.me that i subscribed to a while back.

from their documentation:

- Unroll.me unsubscribes you by following a sender's unsubscribe instructions 24 hours after you've unsubscribed.
- As a backup, we automatically trash all future emails you'll receive from that sender. This is to ensure that if the unsubscribe request fails for some reason, you'll still never receive an email from that sender.

It seems the service accesses your email via IMAP using Oauth. then uses this access to scan emails and pick out the unsubscribe URLs. However it also retains access and trashes any of the emails that get through.

Seems a lot of access for what the service provides, but it was what i signed up for.